# Flutter Push and Pop returning to wrong screen when browsing category lists and Bloc

Tags: flutter, navigation, state

So framework of an app consuming an api and i'm getting there. I have a category browse screen you can tap a cat and then browse then next level down and there's an AppBar provided back button.

The issue is that i push to the next category screen, calling it with the parent code of the category which it fetches and displays.

But when the back button pops the previous screen it shows the same list of categories that was currently being displayed. So the depth is correct but the display of the screen isn't. If you browse 3 levels down then there would be 3 popped screens but each still showing the last level.

In my code i can see that the api isn't being called when popping back.

I have tried a Stateless and Stateful approach but both do the same.

I have added a key to the whole page but does the same

I am using flutter_block in the page to handle the events of getting the data from the api.

I am missing something really silly here. So when a page is pushed, what actually gets pushed onto the stack? in the case of a Stateless Widget (so the page is stateless and the data comes from the bloc) i don't see why the whole page isn't 'cached' onto the stack to be popped.

It's difficult to post code as it's not a self contained segment. my push is

Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => CategoriesPage(startCode: state.categorylist[position].code)));

And the pop is provided by the default AppBar.

Any pointers?

thanks
Paul